# React Native TextInput value keep on refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, edit, textinput

I have these paragraphs that I stored in an array. Then I map them to display buttons on my app where each of it is holding the paragraph id. So when a user clicks one specific button, it will pass the paragraph id to a function to get the data from the database and display it to the react native TextInput.

I've tried to reduce my code as much as possible. So here is how it looked like in my code :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open_parag: false, parag: [], update_parag_text: ''
    }
}

async componentDidMount(){
    const user_id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id');
    if(user_id){
        this._loadEssayOutlineAttemptPreview(user_id);
    }
}

_loadEssayOutlineAttemptPreview(user_id){
    var outlineId = this.props.navigation.state.params.outlineId;
    EssayOutlineController.loadEssayOutlineAttempt(user_id, outlineId).then(data=>{
      if(data.status == true){
        this.setState({
          parag: data.outline_attempt.parag,
        })
      }
    });
}

_getCurrentParag(parag_id){
  EssayOutlineController.loadOneOutlineAttemptParag(parag_id).then(data=>{
    if(data.status == true){
      this.setState({ update_parag_text: data.parag.paragraph })
    }
  });
}

openParag = (parag_id) => {
    this.setState({ open_parag: true }); 
    this._getCurrentParag(parag_id);
}

_displayParagBtn(){
  if(this.state.parag.length > 0){
    return this.state.parag.map((data, i)=>
      <View key={i} style={[ styles.sideButton, { backgroundColor: Colors.default } ]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.openParag(data.id)}>
          <Text style={[styles.sideButtonTitle, { color: Colors.white }]}>PARAGRAPH</Text>
          <Text style={[styles.sideButtonIcon, { color: Colors.white }]}>{i+1}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

_displayOpenParag(){
  if(this.state.open_parag == true){
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.openBox}>
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Comfortaa-Bold' }}>PARAGRAPH CONTENT : </Text>
          <TextInput multiline={true} numberOfLines={6}
            onChangeText={(update_parag_text) => this.setState({update_parag_text})}
            value={this.state.update_parag_text}
          />
          { this.RenderFormErrors('update_parag_text') }
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View style={[ AppStyles.bgWhite, {width: '90%', height: '100%'}]}>
            <ScrollView scrollEnabled={true}>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
          <View style={{width: '10%', height: '100%'}}>
            { this._displayParagBtn() }
          </View>
        </View>
        { this._displayOpenParag() }
      </View>
    );
}
```

If you check from my code above, I load the paragraphs data in `componentDidMount` and set a state. When doing the rendering, I have called the `_displayParagBtn()` function in order to display the paragraph button. When the button is clicked, it will trigger the `openParag` function with the paragraph id been passed and that is how the `TextInput` opened.

From the `openParag` function, I have called another function to load the paragraph data from database and set the current paragraph in a state so that I can display it to the `TextInput` when it's opened.

Everything is working fine with passing the parameter and opening the exact data, but when I try to do editing on my `TextInput`, the data keep on refreshing causing me not be able to edit the existing text. I wonder if it's occured so because of the way I do the fetching and displaying data. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is more clearly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970276/is-using-async-componentdidmount-good), `this.setState` gets called at a delayed time when updating `update_parag_text` in state.