# Array only gets data when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I'm going to a new route (/category/name-of-category) that renders my Category component, the array I'm trying console.log is empty. BUT when I refresh the page, the array gets data? What am I doing wrong? Im not so good at explaining, so I created a video for it.

**Video of the problem:**

[image]

**This is my Category Component where I console.log the array:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PodcastList from './PodcastList'
import { podcastCategories } from './api'

export default class Category extends Component {

  render() {
    const categoryId = this.props.match.params.categoryId
    const categoryName = this.props.match.params.categoryName
    const currentCategory = podcastCategories.filter(category => category.slug === categoryName)
    console.log(currentCategory)
     return (
      <div className='container'>
        <PodcastList key={categoryId} categoryId={categoryId} name={categoryName} amount='100' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**My child component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PodcastItem from './PodcastItem'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import slugify from 'slugify'
import { fetchPodcastCategory } from './api'

export default class PodcastList extends Component {

  state = {
    podcasts: [],
    loading: true,
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    const categoryId = this.props.categoryId
    const totalAmount = this.props.amount
    const podcasts = await fetchPodcastCategory(categoryId, totalAmount);
      this.setState({
        podcasts,
        loading: false,
      })
  }

  render() {
    const podcasts = this.state.podcasts
    const { name, amount, categoryId } = this.props

    let description;
            if (amount === '100') {
              description = (
                        <p>Populäraste poddarna inom {name}</p>
              )
            } else {
              description = (
                <p>Topp {amount} poddar inom {name} -&nbsp;
                <Link to={`/kategori/${slugify(name.toLowerCase())} `}>
                 Visa Topp 100
              </Link>
            </p>
              )
            }

      return (
         <div className='row category-list'>
            <div className='col-md-12'>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            { description }
            {podcasts.map((pod) => {
                const podId = pod.id.attributes['im:id']
                const podImage300 = pod['im:image'][0].label.replace('55x55bb-85', '300x300bb-75')
                const podImage600 = pod['im:image'][1].label.replace('60x60bb-85', '600x600bb-75')
                const podImage900 = pod['im:image'][2].label.replace('170x170bb-85', '900x900bb-75')
                const podImages = { podImage300, podImage600, podImage900 }
                const podName = pod['im:name'].label
                return (
                    <div key={podId} className='pod-box'>
                    <PodcastItem id={podId} image={podImages} name={podName}/>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

**My Api.js:**

```
import Feed from 'feed-to-json-promise'

export async function fetchPodcastCategory (categoryId, amount) {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/podcast/${categoryId}/${amount}`);
  const podcasts = await response.json();

  return podcasts.feed.entry;
}

export async function fetchPodcast (podId) {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/podcast/${podId}`);
  const podcasts = await response.json();

  return podcasts.results;
}

export async function fetchPodcastEpisodes (feedUrl) {
  const feed = new Feed();
  const episodes = await feed.load(`/api/podcast/episodes?feedurl=${feedUrl}`)
  return episodes;
}


export const podcastCategories = [
  { id: '1301', name: 'Konst och kultur', slug: 'konst-och-kultur'},
  { id: '1303', name: 'Komedi och humor', slug: 'komedi-och-humor' },
  { id: '1304', name: 'Utbildning', slug: 'utbildning' },
  { id: '1305', name: 'Barn och familj', slug: 'barn-och-familj' },
  { id: '1307', name: 'Hälsa', slug: 'halsa' },
  { id: '1309', name: 'TV och Film', slug: 'tv-och-film' },
  { id: '1310', name: 'Musik', slug: 'musik' },
  { id: '1311', name: 'Nyheter och politik', slug: 'nyheter-och-politik' },
  { id: '1314', name: 'Religion och andlighet', slug: 'religion-och-andlighet' },
  { id: '1315', name: 'Vetenskap och medicin', slug: 'vetenskap-och-medicin' },
  { id: '1316', name: 'Sport och fritid', slug: 'sport-och-fritid' },
  { id: '1318', name: 'Tenik', slug: 'teknik' },
  { id: '1321', name: 'Affärer', slug: 'affarer' },
  { id: '1323', name: 'Spel och hobby', slug: 'spel-och-hobby' },
  { id: '1324', name: 'Samhälle och kultur', slug: 'samhalle-och-kultur' },
  { id: '1325', name: 'Myndighet och organisation', slug: 'myndighet-och-organisation' },
]
```

**when I console.log: `podcastCategories` & `categoryName`**
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47970276/6124657

Comment: What you mean? My componentDidMount() works in PodcastList.js. But in Category.js I'm just trying to filter an array and console.log what i get? But that only works if I refresh the page?

Comment: Maybe prop categoryName doesn't have a value when the component renders the first time? Could you check it?

Comment: I tried console-log categoryName and i get the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I really tought it was something fuzzy going on. So I tried to to do this in the terminal:

1. `killall -9 node`
2. `ps ax`

and after that restart my node.js server. And for some reason now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the `.api` files that you're bringing in?

This is a guess... since I can't see the full picture but it seems like something isn't coming in properly from the `.api` file.

Can you `console.log(categoryName)` and `console.log(podcastCategories)` before console logging `currentCategory`? Also is there a parent for `Category`? If so, please post the code for that.

Sorry. I would comment rather than answer but I don't have enough points yet. :(

Comment: I have added the .api to my question now. No there is is no parent for Category.

Comment: And I can console.log both categoryName & podcastCategories and get the the values.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check `categoryId` because `<PodcastList key={categoryId}` with the same `key` will be treated as already mounted and only updated with new props - `componentDidMount` won't be called/fired.

Answer (score 0):

Jonas, your code works now because `category.slug = categoryName` is an assignment, not a check of truth.  It will return the truthiness of the value assigned to `category.slug`, i.e. `categoryName`.  So seems like `categoryName` is defined, but is not strictly equal to `category.slug`.  Holly E asked a good question--can you show what `categoryName` shows in the console?  And what about `podcastCategories`?  If you add that to your code above, we should be able to see why the strict equality is not doing what is expected.

Comment: Your right.. my bad. I have updated the question now with what I get when I console.log categoryName & podcastCategories @ZebGir