# Await for Redux thunk in react lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'd been working with **React & Redux** for some time when a work 
colleague saw some code I wrote and commented on it.

*SomeComponent.js*

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.fetchPosts();  

    if (this.props.posts.length < 1)
      return navigateTo( /* someOtherPlace */);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
          {this.props.posts.map(
            (postData, i) => <Post key={i} {...postData}/>
          )}
        </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ posts }) => ({
  posts: posts.list,
  isFetching: posts.isFetching
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(SomeComponent);
```

*actions/posts.js*

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestPosts());
  let posts;
  try {
    posts = (await api.get('/posts')).data
  } catch (e) {
    posts = e;
  }
  dispatch(receivePosts(posts));
}
```

He basically said that I shouldn't be awaiting for `fetchPosts()` action, instead I should just call it, and let it update props, re-render and perform the conditional navigation in `componentDidUpdate` which when he said it, it totally made sense to me.

But now I keep asking myself if what I was doing was really that bad, potencially buggy or just a bad practice that added more complexity.

He didn't mention the reasons why it was wrong other than it wasn't the React way of doing it.

**EDIT:** Added code snippet showing that the approach actually does work and doesn't perform faulty reads.

[image: Edit Await in componentDidMount]

Comment: I honestly don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970276/is-using-async-componentdidmount-good

Answer (score 0):

So there is small issue in your case

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.fetchPosts();  

    if (this.props.posts.length < 1)
      return navigateTo( /* someOtherPlace */);
}
```

Here `await` will wait till the fetchPosts is completed provided it returns a promise. Now fetchPosts will dispatch an action that will only result in the props being updated and another render triggered to update the posts in the component. So even if you wait for fetchPosts to complete the `posts` are not updated in the same render cycle and hence using `this.props.posts.length` won't return you the result corresponding to the latest posts update in redux store. The result being that you are unnecessarily waiting for the fetchPosts to complete and performing a check which will lead to a faulty result

Better approach is to work like

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();  
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     if(this.props.posts !== prevProps.posts && this.props.posts.length < 1) {
          return navigateTo( /* someOtherPlace */);
     }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
          {this.props.posts.map(
            (postData, i) => <Post key={i} {...postData}/>
          )}
        </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I added a small code that shows that actually no faulty result happens, check the console output of it.