# Async React component lifecycle methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If lifecycle methods on React components are marked `async`, are they treated differently?

```js
    default class MyComponent extends Component {
      state = {};

      async componentDidMount() {
        await this.fillQuestions();
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970276/is-using-async-componentdidmount-good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between the way they're being called. **`async` only means that the function will return Promise.** and since React doesn't expect any return value, there's no difference between the two from React's point of view.

However, you can use `async` when you want to `await` for some other promise inside your lifecycle hook.

Take a look at the following medium article:
https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802