# ComponentDidMount etc doesnt fire function in order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I noticed that the componentDidMount sometimes doesn't fire in order.

```
componentDidMount(){
 function1();
 function2();
 function3();
}
```

I noticed that function 2 sometimes inconsistently start before function 1 finished. 
As of right now I just put my function 2 inside function 1 at the end of the code. However, is there a better way to do this? And why its doing this?

Comment: Can you please post the whole component code? Thanks!

Comment: What's in `function1` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question will definitely call those functions in that order.

However, it sounds like those functions do asynchronous work. If so, that code will *start* the work of all three functions (in order) and then that work will overlap, and there's no reason the work started by `function2` wouldn't complete before the work started by `function1` does.

In that case, you need to provide some coordination between them if you want `function2` to wait to start its process until `function1` is done (and so on for `function2` and `function3`). For instance, if they return promises, then:

```
function1()
.then(() => function2())
.then(() => function3())
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

There I've assumed all three functions want to be called with no arguments.

If they take callbacks instead, then:

```
function1(() => {
    function2(() => {
        function3();
    });
});
```

Since callback APIs vary about how they report errors, I haven't tried to include error handling in that last example.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for `componentDidMount`

In most situations, it's well enough.

```
async componentDidMount(){
 await function1();
 await function2();
 await function3();
}
```

Refer: related QA in specific: [Is using async componentDidMount() good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970276/is-using-async-componentdidmount-good)

Comment: If you do this, you need a `try`/`catch` to handle errors, since React doesn't do anything with the promise this returns. Personally, I don't think it's best practice to return a promise from a framework lifecycle method that nothing is going to use, but it's workable with a `try`/`catch`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right. In our practice, the only situation needs to handle errors that occur with API requests, which has been handled by common service. So it is case by case in my opinion. But I really agree with your idea.