# Ionic/React/TypeScript,using react-router history.push, history.replace and history.goBack Animation triggers twice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-router, ionic-react

So basically i'm Working on a Ionic/React Typescript application and there is this strange page transition that occurs twice when I navigate thought the app (see gif below)

I checked and it's not the renders that's call twice as the componentWillMount/didMount/willUnmount are all trigger once like it should for the pusher page and also for the pushed page.

[image]

As you can see, the transition always happens twice and found no solution anywhere ...
Versions used :
 - Ionic : 5.2.1
 - React : 16.9.0 (npm package)
 - Typescript 3.6.3 (npm package)

```
Here is the code for the page with the "Diplomes" Title:
class Diplome extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {

  // Function who redirect to the url for edit an situation
  redirectUrlToEditSituation = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/app/edit/diplome/', null);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <IonPage>
          <IonHeader>
            <IonToolbar>
                <ButtonHambToolBar />
                <ToolBarLogo toolbarName={ToolBarName.DIPLOME}/>
            </IonToolbar>
          </IonHeader>
          <IonContent>
            <FabButtonAction ClickHandler={() => this.redirectUrlToEditSituation()} icon={add}/>
            <GenericList type={ModelType.DIPLOME}/>
          </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    );
  }
}

export default (Diplome);
```

And here is the page with the "Editions" title when click on the button :

```
class DiplomeEdit extends Component<DiplomeEditProps, {
    dataIsLoad: boolean,
    label_field: string,
    isAnCreate: boolean,
    openModalDelete: boolean,
    isValidation: boolean,
    currentDiplome: any
}>
{

    constructor(props: DiplomeEditProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            label_field: '',
            isAnCreate: true,
            openModalDelete: false,
            dataIsLoad: false,
            currentDiplome: '',
            isValidation: false,
        };
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        console.log("component will mount");
        await this.getCurrentDiplomeToUpdate();
    }

    // Function who check if they are param on the url
    // If param exist get the current diplome on the store
    getCurrentDiplomeToUpdate = async () => {
        if (this.props.match.params.idDiplome !== undefined) {

            const diplomes: DiplomeInterface[] = this.props.diplomes;
            if (diplomes.length > 0) {
                const currentDiplomeReceive: DiplomeInterface | undefined = diplomes.find((res: DiplomeInterface) => {
                    return this.props.match.params.idDiplome === res.idDiplome;
                });

                if (currentDiplomeReceive !== undefined) {
                    this.setState({
                        isAnCreate: false,
                        label_field: currentDiplomeReceive.labelDiplome,
                        currentDiplome: currentDiplomeReceive,
                        dataIsLoad: true,
                    });
                }
            }

        } else {
            this.setState({
                isAnCreate: true,
                dataIsLoad: true,
            });
        }
    }

    // Function who render update button
    renderUpdateButton = () => {
        return (
            <div className="contenaire_button_action_situation_edit">
                <Button hidden={this.state.isAnCreate}
                    onClick={() => this.openOrCloseModalDeleteDialog()}
                    className="button_delete_situation">Supprimer</Button>
                <Button
                    onClick={e => this.actionClick()}
                    className="button_action_situation_edit">Enregistrer</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    // Function who delete diplome on the databse and on the store
    removeDiplome = async () => {
        await REQUEST.deleteDiplome(this.state.currentDiplome.idDiplome);
        store.dispatch(DELETE_DIPLOME(this.state.currentDiplome.idDiplome));
        this.props.history.replace('/app/diplomes');
    }

    // Function who get the label and id for create new diplome on the databae
    // Reset the state to the default init
    saveDiplome = async () => {
        const obj: DiplomeInterface = {
            idDiplome: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
            labelDiplome: this.state.label_field.toLowerCase(),
        };
        this.setState({
            label_field: '',
            isAnCreate: false,
            openModalDelete: false,
        });
        await REQUEST.postDiplome(obj);
        store.dispatch(ADD_DIPLOME(obj));
        //this.props.history.replace('/app/diplomes');
        window.smartAlert("Diplome ajouté avec succès", "success", 5000);
        this.props.history.goBack();
    }

    // Function who update a diplome on the store
    // Need the current diplome
    // Label update
    updateDiplome = async () => {
        const currentDiplomeReceive: DiplomeInterface = this.state.currentDiplome;

        const obj: DiplomeInterface = {
            idDiplome: currentDiplomeReceive.idDiplome,
            labelDiplome: this.state.label_field,
        };

        if (this.props.userConnected.typeAccount === TypeConnect.ADMIN) {
            await REQUEST.updateDiplome(obj);
            store.dispatch(UPDATE_DIPLOME(obj));
            this.props.history.replace('/app/diplomes');
        }
    }

    // Function who checked what action we need
    actionClick = () => {
        if (this.state.isAnCreate) {
            this.saveDiplome();
        } else {
            this.updateDiplome();
        }
    }

    // Function call when input change
    inputChange = (e: any) => {
        this.setState({
            label_field: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    // Function who change the openModalDelete to true
    openOrCloseModalDeleteDialog = () => {
        if (this.props.userConnected.typeAccount === TypeConnect.ADMIN) {
            this.setState({
                openModalDelete: !this.state.openModalDelete,
            });
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <IonPage>
                <IonHeader>
                    <IonToolbar className="task_cat_toolbar">
                        <IonBackButton
                            className="situation_edit_back_button" />
                        <ToolBarLogo toolbarName={ToolBarName.EDIT} />
                    </IonToolbar>
                </IonHeader>

                <IonContent>
                    <div className="contenaire_edit">
                        <div className="contenaire_form_situation">
                            <div className="contenaire_field">
                                <TextField
                                    onChange={e => this.inputChange(e)}
                                    value={this.state.label_field}
                                    className="field_form_situation"
                                    label="Libelle" />
                            </div>

                            <div className="container_task_situation_edit">

                                {!this.state.dataIsLoad && <SpinnerCircular />}

                                {this.renderUpdateButton()}

                                {
                                    this.state.openModalDelete &&
                                    <DialogDelete
                                        actionRemove={() => this.removeDiplome()}
                                        open={this.state.openModalDelete}
                                        actionCloseModal={() => this.openOrCloseModalDeleteDialog()} />
                                }

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </IonContent>

            </IonPage>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state: DiplomeEditProps) => ({
    diplomes: state.diplomes,
    network: state.network,
    role: state.role,
    userConnected: state.userConnected,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DiplomeEdit);
```

Comment: you dont have a github link?

Comment: @bbortt I can't sorry but feel free to ask question if you think you know the issue ^^

Comment: You’re making an async call in `componentWillMount`. What happens if you move that to `componentDidMount`? The way async/await code works internally may be biting you here.

Comment: @rob3c Thx for your feedback but no the removal of async doesn't change anything, the console.log(), trigger once every time with or without the async.

Comment: @AlexFrau Just to clarify, are you saying you removed the call to `getCurrentDiplomeToUpdate` from `componentWillMount` and moved it to be called from `componentDidMount` instead, and you still have the same problem? It’s not clear to me from your reply if that’s what you tried specifically.

Comment: yes same problem still

Answer (score 0):

You just can't declare `componentWillMount` lifecycle method as async.

From the [React docs about `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

```
Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.
```

and [React blog "Update on Async Rendering"](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) (03/2018):

```
One of the biggest lessons we’ve learned is that some of our legacy component
lifecycles tend to encourage unsafe coding practices. They are:

    componentWillMount
    componentWillReceiveProps
    componentWillUpdate

These lifecycle methods have often been misunderstood and subtly misused; 
furthermore, we anticipate that their potential misuse may be more problematic
with async rendering. Because of this, we will be adding an “UNSAFE_” prefix
to these lifecycles in an upcoming release. (Here, “unsafe” refers not to 
security but instead conveys that code using these lifecycles will be more 
likely to have bugs in future versions of React, especially once async 
rendering is enabled.)
```

Victoria Fluharty wrote the helpful post [componentWillMount() vs componentDidMount()](https://dev.to/torianne02/componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount-5f0n) on that topic.

**tl;dr**: if you have async logic, you need to move it to `componentDidMount()` (or migrate to more modern approaches like functional components with [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) instead of the partly-deprecated lifecycle methods.

You can declare `componentDidMount()` as `async`, but there might be slight caveats:

- [Is using async componentDidMount() good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970276/is-using-async-componentdidmount-good)
- [How To Use Async Await in React (componentDidMount Async)](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/)

Comment: Ok thx that's very helpful ! I'll investigate with the links you gave me ! I'll keep you updated !

Comment: Thank you for providing detailed confirmation to the answer I provided in my comment three days ago 